# Refactoring Swift UIViewPropertyAnimators out of massive view controller

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, refactoring, uiviewpropertyanimator

I am trying to refactor my Swift massive view controller which now has >900 lines (too many).

How can I separate the creation of my `UIViewPropertyAnimators` (~100 lines) from my main `UIViewController`? 
The thing is that the `UIViewPropertyAnimators` need reference to the `view` property and the `UIViews` they are animating. Do I create a `struct` with a `weak var` to which I assign the `view` reference by dependency injection? I would also need to refer to the `UIView` objects somehow. 
Not sure what is the best way to refactor this without creating a kind of circularity. Any ideas?

**Addition**:

As all animators only related to part of the window I have now created a child view controller and moved the animators there. I think this is also a viable solution. I had to add delegate pattern. At the end, the parent view controller is ~100 lines shorter and I have 'separated concern' as they say.

Comment: you can create extension for uiview, i think UIViewPropertyAnimators not the only problem. Read about MVVM

Comment: put your `UIViewPropertyAnimators` in a separate file, then make a protocol in that file and access your `view` property by defining a `delegate` of type `UIViewController`

Answer (score 1):

For example:

New File named PropertyAnimators

In that file import all the libraries that you need.  Then extend the original view controller like so:

```
extension UIViewControllerName: UIViewController, (any other delegates that you need) {
//PropertyAnimators code
}
```